# Is my method correct for the calculation of $f(x)$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$f(x)^{2007}=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{(t)^{2006}}{2+t^2}$$
$$=>2007f(x)^{2006}=\Biggr[\frac{f(t)^{2006}}{2+t^2}\Biggr]_{0}^{x}$$
$$=>f(x^{2006})\Biggr(2007-\frac{1}{2+x^2}\Biggr)=-\frac{f(0)^{2006}}{2}$$
$$=>f(x)=\sqrt[2006]{-\frac{f(0)^{2006}}{2}.\Biggr(\frac{1}{2007-\frac{1}{2+x^2}}\Biggr)}$$

Comment: Is the first line of the question meant to be $f\left(x\right)^{2007}=\int_0^x\frac{f\left(t\right)^{2006}}{2+t^2}\mathrm dt$

Comment: Yes, that is the first line of the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some typographical errors.  If what you intended is $$f(x)^{2007} = \int_{t=0}^x \frac{f(t)^{2006}}{2+t^2} \, dt,$$ then we first observe that $$f(0)^{2007} = \int_{t=0}^0 \frac{f(t)^{2006}}{2+t^2} \, dt,$$ and provided $f$ is well-defined, we must have $f(0) = 0$.  Next, we have by the Fundamental Theorem $$\frac{d}{dx} \left[f(x)^{2007}\right] = \frac{f(x)^{2006}}{2+x^2} - \frac{f(0)^{2006}}{2+0^2} = \frac{f(x)^{2006}}{2+x^2}.$$  But by the chain rule, we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x)^{2007}\right] = 2007 f(x)^{2006} f'(x).$$  Thus $$2007 f'(x) = \frac{1}{2+x^2}$$ for all $f(x) \ne 0$.  It follows that $$f(x) = \frac{\tan^{-1} (x/\sqrt{2})}{2007\sqrt{2}} + C,$$ and the requirement $f(0) = 0$ implies $C = 0$.  Thus there are two solutions:  the trivial solution $f(x) = 0$, and $$f(x) = \frac{\tan^{-1}(x/\sqrt{2})}{2007\sqrt{2}}.$$

---

As you can see, you made one critical error:  you did not perfom the differentiation of $f(x)^{2007}$ correctly.  You must apply the chain rule here.  A secondary error is not recognizing that we must have $f(0) = 0$.